# Slow SQLite update with a simple set expression?

Tags: sqlite

I run a

```
update mytable set b=a/1000;
```

and it takes hours on a 20 Mio. row/6GB database.

Is there any tweak I can do it make it faster?

Comment: Well, updating 20 million rows is gonna take some time, no matter how you go about it.

Comment: This expression will update all rows in your table. This isn't a simple expression, it's a really massive operation

Comment: Sure, but hours? Writing 6GB of data is much faster and this operation is pretty simple, I thought.

Comment: There's nothing simple about modifying 20M rows inside a transaction, creating all those transaction log records, updating indexes etc. Moreover, SQLite is an *embedded* database, it can't use multithreading or the optimizations used by server products. If you want to do such a modification, why don't you just add a calculated column?

Comment: So can I skip any of the overhead? I actually have no indices. Loading more than 100 columns with 20 Mio. rows from a CSV and simple preprocessing took not much more than 30min. Maybe I should have done the extra column outside SQLite, but why is the update so much slower?

Comment: You can try running  `PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF; PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;` beforehand. Just make sure nothing uses the database in the meantime and make a backup beforehand though.